# a secondary wifi router to connect legacy/untrusted (unpatchable) devices

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, security, wireless-router

Thanks in advance for grace and patience as I try to understand a potential network configuration...

I would like to employ a separate wireless router to connect untrusted (unpatchable) devices to. Example: a nature camera placed in a non-sensitive location outdoors, and an older tablet used as a wall-mounted dedicated screen for the nature cam (as it might be hard to justify buying a new tablet just for only this one use).

My primary devices would remain connected to a trusted network on a separate wireless router. Both routers would ultimately be connected to one modem. The ISP provides only one IP address through this modem.

From a network security perspective, is there a secure way to do this? If an unpatched device on the untrusted network was compromised, is there any possibility that the security of the primary (trusted) network could also be compromised?

Comment: Would daisy-chaining wireless routers in a certain order be advised? (modem > trusted network > untrusted network... vs. modem > untrusted > trusted). I've seen both suggested and am scratching my head a bit.

Would connecting both wireless routers to a _wired_ router result in sandboxing the 2 from each other? (modem > wired router > trusted and untrusted routers connected to wired router via separate Ethernet cables).

Answer (score 1):

There is no single absolute answer to this as it depends on the threat, but in general terms -

You could have the configuration:

```
ISP Router ------------ Insecure Device 1
                   +--- Insecure Device 2
                   |
                   +--- WAN - Router 2
                               |
                               LAN
                               |
                               +--------  Patched Device 1
                               +--------  Patched Device 2
                               ...
```

You would further need to ensure that Router 2 does NAT (which is acting as a firewall), and you would want to ensure that the LAN subnet on Router 2 is different to router 1 - eg if router 1 is 192.168.x.x, router 2 should use something like 10.0.x.x for its local network.

The disadvantage is that devices going through ROUTER2 are double-natted, but in todays world that likely makes very little difference.

As a bonus, if you at least partially trust insecure devices, you should be able to access them from your Patched devices - this is not bullet proof, but pretty good because the insecure devices can't see the patched devices, only the Want interface of Router 2.

Comment: NAT doesn't act as a firewall _especially_ in this situation where a malicious device is directly on the same subnet as Router2's WAN interface – the supposed security of NAT comes from it being impossible to have a route to the "inner" private addresses, but this particular layout makes it quite possible, and only the _actual_ firewall of Router2 would prevent unwanted packets from going in. Of course, just a regular botnet-infected device won't even bother with something like that, but if the question was e.g. about separating tenants or customers who don't trust each other, it would matter.

Comment: @user1868 Absolutely disagree here.  A packet from a Patched Device  responding to an Insecure Device would not be able to find its way back out the network as patched Device 1's IP address would be rewritten.

Comment: That wouldn't mean it "would not be able to find its way back out", it would only mean the Insecure Device wouldn't _recognize_ the responses due to them arriving from a different IP address... but in practice, the address *wouldn't* be rewritten, as the outbound replies match an existing state entry in Router2's NAT that was previously established by the inbound packets, and since those weren't NATed, no NAT will be applied in reverse either. (Most home routers just rely on the Linux iptables + conntrack system for firewalling and NAT, and it behaves exactly like that.)

Comment: (The 'nat' table in iptables is only processed once per flow, not per packet – once the flow is recorded in conntrack, any NATing and un-NATing in both directions is done by conntrack and the rules aren't looked at anymore.) It's something I had a chance to test in a real environment that I kind of co-managed, with a Linux machine being used as a gateway and doing routing + NAT for a few dozen separate organization networks – they had very typical iptables NAT for outbound traffic, and had firewall rules blocking packets _between_ organizations, but did not have any for packets from outside...

Comment: The two comments above are real precious notes. They make me wanna test if my home router has any security measures at all in preventing its "WAN LAN" hosts from initiating communication with its LAN hosts. By the way other than having stateful rules in the forward chain, the man page in `nft` actually gives another approach (`fib daddr . iif type != { local, broadcast, multicast } drop`) that might be helpful in this case. Seems to work as desired for my VM that is connected to an "internal" bridge when I put it in `type filter hook prerouting priority dstnat` with `iifname "$WAN"` added.

Comment: Also IIRC {pf,opn}sense actually has a specific switch for you to decide whether it should block traffics with destination address in the private IP blocks from getting past it from the WAN side.

Comment: Just coming back to send thanks to all for the responses here and throughout. We had a medical situation which put this project on the back burner but I'll chime back with what I learn as we get started with this again. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

> Would daisy-chaining wireless routers in a certain order be advised? (modem > trusted network > untrusted network... vs. modem > untrusted > trusted).

Both options can be used, both aren't ideal.

With `modem > trusted network > untrusted network`, all traffic from the untrusted network will go *through* the trusted one, and the untrusted router naturally has a route to the trusted network (due to being directly part of that network). In this case, it will only become secure **if** the router managing the untrusted network has explicit firewall rules blocking traffic to the trusted network's IP address range.

With `modem > untrusted network > trusted network`, all traffic from the trusted network will go through the untrusted one. That's fine, as long as you don't expect the untrusted devices to break into the untrusted router itself (which may also be in the category of "legacy unpatchable devices") – and I've heard about cases of this happening and malware on the router doing TLS interception (rare but not unheard of) or just sending spam.

> Would connecting both wireless routers to a wired router result in sandboxing the 2 from each other?

Yes, but depends on what kind of router it is.

If it's just another "home gateway" kind of router, with yet another layer of NAT and everything – yes, everything would work, though in that case I'd look into whether the "inner" Wi-Fi routers could have their NAT feature disabled (but keeping the firewalls still enabled, of course).

If it's a router that is natively capable of managing multiple networks (i.e. each port a different LAN), you wouldn't really need the wireless routers *as routers* anymore at that point; you could use *this* router to manage both subnets (act as gateway for both, do DHCP for both) and use firewall rules on this router to block traffic in the unwanted direction (similar to the first example). The Wi-Fi devices could then run as access points. This is how many enterprise networks are run, with several LANs going back to a single gateway (often in the form of VLANs) and the gateway's firewall deciding who can access what.